# Make the "unanswered" tab more manageable by hiding questions from it more aggressively

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

The main use-case for the "Unanswered" tab is to find questions that have no good answer to try answering them.

The problem is that the list has many questions you can't provide useful feedback on:

1. The question is poor and needs further clarification.

   - *Possible solution: The questions **you** downvoted could be hidden from your "unanswered" tab*
2. The question already has an answer that you or another person provided, but it didn't reach the [arbitrary upvotes limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18870/why-does-the-unanswered-questions-tab-show-questions-that-have-answers) used to hide the question from the "unanswered" list.

   - *Possible solution: The questions **you** answered or with answers you upvoted (even if its score is 0=+1-1) could be removed from your  "unanswered" list.*
3. You just don't know the answer to a question (and either interested in knowing it or not interested at all).

   - *Possible solution: Either let me [hide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7603/the-ability-to-hide-questions) the question or make a question I upvote/favorite disappear from the "unanswered" list.*
4. Some questions are answered by the reporter in a comment (like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574478/javascript-insertbefore-method)

Any other ideas for getting the "unanswered" list more manageable? I'm mainly thinking about the "my tags" use-case.

[edited, the original question was not well-thought-out and was more like a dupe of [The Ability to Hide Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7603/the-ability-to-hide-questions). Thanks to the commenters who helped me realize this]

Comment: I don't see the difference from this and the other, if you would be able to hide questions in the system, then you would be able to hide them from the unanswered tab.

Comment: This one is more specific than that one. I have asked it separately, because the other question focused on "I don't want to see this active question".

Comment: Also it could definitely hide questions you answered (without upvotes) or that has answers you upvoted. I guess I'll morph the question...

Comment: Now it's no dupe anymore. I especially like point 2. I wouldn't stumble over question I have already answered.

Comment: Some good suggestions in there.  Normally someone brings this up and just wants to hide all questions with an answer.  You at least gave some thought to it first: +1

Comment: To be fair, not at first, see the comments and the revision history :)

Answer (score 3):

Some good ideas there, especially about using votes to hide questions. I'll go over each of your 4 scenarios real quick:

1. Unfortunately, there's a problem.  When a question is edited, you probably want to see it again.  And if you still don't like it, you can't re-downvote it so easily.
2. This makes a lot of sense to me.  However, see the next point.
3. By the time you implement the "hide from my view" option, you may just as well use that to handle scenarios 1 & 2, also.  The problem here, though, is that I think it would add a lot of traffic and complexity to the system. I still think a better sort option, maybe combined with suggestion #2, would work better.
4. If you see a question that's really *answered* in a comment, copy that comment to a new community wiki answer of your own (so you don't earn rep for someone else's work and they can take ownership easily later if they come back) and get someone to upovte it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Re 4: the problem is that many questions don't get enough activity (and upvotes), probably because regulars on SO aren't that into some topics. So I can definitely create a community wiki answer, but it won't solve the problem.

Comment: Re 1: That's a general problem with downvotes, don't you think? I think it deserves a general solution, not specific to the idea of hiding questions you downvoted. E.g. (just thinking aloud, not something I seriously suggest) removing downvotes after a question is edited & upvoted.