# Hide Questions Not Interested In

Tags: feature-request, questions

There are a lot of questions that I am generally not interested in viewing either because I don't know anything about what they're discussing or don't have an interest in it. This gets cluttered after a while when you're searching for questions that are interesting to you and you keep getting the same ones over and over again. I think a useful feature would be something like Facebook's "Hide" functionality where you can just click a box or something and it will effectively hide the question from you. It would be question-centric instead of based on tags, since some questions that have tags you're interested in just aren't interesting to you (me, ha).

What say you?

Comment: Read a little more closely. He's not asking about a tag based hide show, but a per-question flag...

Comment: my bad, misread, I've removed my answer and comment

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7603/the-ability-to-hide-questions

Comment: @john - nice find... didn't come up in my search. however, it never really got answered...

Comment: @Jason: Well, it came up in your search. You see the "Related" column on the right? It's number two...

Comment: oh good, close a question that hasn't been answered in either spot.

Comment: Jason, (at least sometimes) the team looks at accumulated votes when deciding where to spend their development effort. But for that to be reliable there has to be *one* authoritative version of each request. The convention is to prefer the earlier one. Go add your vote to 7603 and write an answer explaining you reasoning and (since it looks reasonable to me) your proposed implementation. And while this question is closed, it is not deleted so it serves as a pointer to that earlier question.

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to have a per-user, per-question, persistent hide--show function?

Stack Overflow has near half a million questions right now, and 125,000ish registered users if I calculate right. Call it 10^11 boolean flags, and will only get worse.

I think it will be slow.

Comment: you could store the ids in a cookie on the user's browser

Comment: So multiply the persistence period you are imagining by the number of questions the most active user views in that length of time by the size of the cookie and figure the user's disk load. It is not uncommon for me stack overflow to get more than 1000 new questions a day. Anyone who is really trying to keep up will click past most of them... And how well do the browser cookie databases perform as the number of cookies grows? (Honest question that I have no clue about.)

Comment: not sure really... maybe limit to 100? clean out every week? i dunno... people smarter than i would be implementing this. it could be done after pageload too via jquery, just go through your list and hide ?s with the id in them. i see your point tho if it gets too big, but you could append a time sig that is checked and autodeletes  old ones after any period of time...

Comment: Give each user a limit of 100 questions to hide, and it takes 1.5MB  max.(bit data) assuming every user is active, using this functionality and hiding 100 questions. Also; this is not only for questions one is not interested in, but also for questions that actually have no answers and not yet closed by moderators. Which you can find lots of them while browsing unanswered questions.