# "Sick of this question" button

Tags: feature-request

I find SE an amazingly well thought-out platform in so many respects, so I am a bit puzzled that what I am about to describe has not been solved/addressed yet.

I can specify my interests by keeping a list of tags that I want to follow. However, on the "my tags" unanswered tab (or on any other tab for that matter) I can not choose how the questions are ranked. They seem to be roughly ranked by descending number of votes, with occasionally some fresh stuff thrown in at the top.

As a result, much of this list feels quite stale, since it is made up of questions that have been collecting votes (and dust) for a while.

Hence my request: I would like to be able to click "I'm bored with this question, please don't show it to me for a while." so that my list actually fills up with things I haven't looked at or am not bored with yet, and I don't have to wade through screenfuls of oldtimers to detect a newcomer.

One variation could be "I'm bored with this question, please hide it until someone comes up with an answer of at least 3 upvotes".

Comment: Why don't you just use the customized front page?

Comment: @CodyGray how do I do that?

Comment: @Arjan I guess you are right that it requests the same sort of feature, however I think that this question outlines the underlying "beef" more explicitly, so it is clearer call to arms :)

Comment: Click on the "Stack Overflow" logo, that takes you to the home page. If you've set up favorite and ignored tags, it will automatically algorithmically show questions you're likely to enjoy. It also shows questions similar to those that you've asked and answered.

Comment: @CodyGray I think you haven't read the post carefully :)

Comment: I assumed you must be doing something different than that, because that's one of the primary ways I browse the site and a simple refresh after a few minutes is enough to get a bunch of new questions. I never see anything that's stale. There is *way* too much activity on Stack Overflow for that.

Comment: @CodyGray Interesting. Maybe my tags simply have much lower activity than average.

Comment: That is possible. The other thing I do is I have a list of tags I'm interested in, run a search for all questions with any of those tags, and then filter by "newest". That gets me plenty of questions, too; way more than I ever have time for. Then again, I suppose I do have fairly popular interests, as far as the SO community is concerned.

Comment: I was hoping, based on the title, that this was a new proposal for dealing with repetitive, massively duplicated questions.

Comment: @JoshCaswell harsh... ok well it looks like I'm quite alone on this so I will delete the question.

Comment: You've got three upvotes, and there's no need to _delete_ it just because it's not hugely popular right now. Even highly upvoted feature requests usually stick around for a while before being implemented. At the absolute least, you should wait until noon GMT -7 or so.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's what she (I) said! But no-one seems to take those repetitive-overasked-massively duplicated questions seriously...