# I would like a way to mark a question in the Unanswered "my tags" page as something I'm not interested in or able to answer

Tags: feature-request, tags, unanswered-questions, tag-watching

The `/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags` page gives a list of questions from my favorite tags that are currently considered "unanswered" - they have no up voted or accepted answers. I think it's good to put them in front of me easily, but even though they have one or more tags that I'm interested in, I may not have the knowledge, ability, or interest to write an answer to them. However, they will remain on this page until someone writes an answer.

I would like to be able to dismiss questions from views, like this one, that show me interesting questions. I may choose to share them on my social media to get them views and answers, but I don't want to continually see them. Instead, I want to be able to use views like `unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags` as a queue of things that could use my attention.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7603/the-ability-to-hide-questions (about any question)

Comment: @Nemo I'm not referring to low quality questions. I'm referring to good questions that I can't or don't want to answer. For example, there are currently 103 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers in my tags on Software Engineering. Some of them are appropriately tagged, but I don't have the right knowledge to provide the best answer, so I want it removed from my list. Having questions like this makes it harder to go through this list of questions I'm likely to know something about and keep finding ones I want to answer.

Comment: @ThomasOwens sure, I got it. I'm just saying that I understand your need because I sometimes end up using downvotes *also* for this (which is not ideal).