# Is there a way to hide certain Stack Exchange sites from your feed?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, hot-questions

I am just wondering if I could hide, for example, Inter-Personal Skills questions from appearing in my feed?

Note on tag: I think feature-request is the closest to the right tag, because there is the implicit request for the feature if it does not already exist. I can change that if it is the wrong tag though.

As clarification, I mean this feed:

[image]

<sub>(I looked around a bit (probably not enough) for a similar question, but I couldn't find it.)</sub>

Comment: Ah, I see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7603/the-ability-to-hide-questions?rq=1) and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags?rq=1) which are quite similar. I'm wondering about whole stacks rather than questions or tags. But I'm gonna read through them to see if they answer my question anyway.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by your feed? The "Hot Network Questions" on the right sidebar, or something else?

Comment: Pretty much, but I meant both the HNQ and real-time feed from the main page

Comment: @Aethenosity People downvote pretty liberally on Meta. The only obvious reason I can see is that I'm pretty sure this *is* a duplicate, although if that was the reason, it would be nice if they dug up the duplicate post as well. I'm pretty sure there's a existing post asking how to hide certain stack sites from your feed.

Comment: I can't find it. I remember the post though. The OP said something like "I don't bike, so I don't care about seeing biking questions". Unless it was deleted for some reason.

Comment: I still haven't seen a duplicate question. If someone finds one, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I see that it was my use of the word feed that prevented me from finding the duplicates. Sorry for asking again, I appreciate it guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a customized feed, or a feed at all.

This is just a list of all 100 Hot Network Questions. It's the same for anyone who visit the page.

If you don't want to see this list, e.g. avoid spoilers on Movies.SE, just don't visit this page.

So no, there's no way to hide certain sites there, and I don't think there should be.

Comment: @MaskedMan sidebar is easy to ignore, and there are many userscripts to hide it for those who want. Question here was about se.com default page which lists all the Hot questions.

Answer (score 3):

So, I used the wrong terminology, as Shadow pointed out. So that answer will be marked correct.

For anyone else who may be looking for the same thing, it is best handled through the "advanced tag subscriptions" section in settings.

I was put off by the name before actually checking out myself. I didn't want to filter tags, but whole stacks. However, it's actually handled from the same place.

First, get to it from here:[image: tag filtering location]

Then you'll be at a page that looks like this: [image: advanced tag subscriptions]

Then use this button to show only your filtered stacks and tags, depending on how you set it up. [image: Filtered Questions]

Unfortunately, this isn't the same as the HNQ... not-feed... with certain stacks filtered out. The "activity" button doesn't *seem* to order the questions by hotness points, which is what I would like.

Comment: In the left pane, don't click on *Preferences*.
Instead, click on *Hide communities*. :-)